# Como remover arquivo do controle de fonte do TFS Team System mas não removê-lo do projeto

Tags: team-foundation-server

Eu tenho um aplicativo web que desenvolvo em parceria com outro programador. Existem situações onde não podemos compartilhar um determinado arquivo.
Exemplo: arquivo `nhibernate.cfg` da pasta `bin`.

É possível manter duas versões do mesmo arquivo uma para cada usuário?

Comment: Uma prática comum em controles de versão é ignorar que o arquivo em questão va para o repositório, obrigando, dessa forma, a cada um criar a sua versão do arquivo. Veja se cabe no seu caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu conheço uma maneira que não diria ser a mais elegante, mas funciona...

Quando você incluir um arquivo no seu projeto (pode ser arrastando e soltando dentro da pasta no Solution Explorer) ele vai ficar marcado com + para Adição, se você der um *Undo Pending Changes* o arquivo continuará no seu projeto mas será ignorado.

Como você já possui o arquivo versionado, provavelmente você precisaria remover esse arquivo pra depois executar esse procedimento.

Comment: Boa... vou tentar isso! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer um Branch. No Visual Studio, vá até a aba Team Explorer e abra o Source Control Explorer. Procure na árvore de arquivos o arquivo que você deseja, clique nele com o botão direito do mouse, vá no menu 'Branching and Merging', e selecione 'Branch'. Clique em ok na tela que irá aparecer.

Não tenho certeza se isso vai funcionar do jeito que você precisa, mas vale a pena tentar...

Comment: pesquisei sobre o branch, mas no meu caso naum vai resolver. de qualquer forma muito obrigao!